# Does above code load entire fuseki dataset into memory or keep it at server side?

Tags: rdf, jena, fuseki

When I use this snippet of code, I find it issue a GET query to fuseki server, and after I issue more SPARQL query using this model, no more query issued. So is DatasetFactory load entire fuseki dataset into memory? If it is, how to avoid this kind of problem when I want to use dataset?

```
    Dataset dataset = DatasetFactory.create("http://localhost:3030/movie");
    Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();
```

And why do I need a dataset from client side? I need it for generic purpose rule inference. I want to dynamically load my rules from somewhere and using this dataset for inference. I don't want to use embedded tdb, because fuseki seems better.

Comment: Yes, it is loaded into memory. For inference, the rules and the data probably need to be in the same place.

Comment: @AndyS what about config the rule and the data both in the server side? I have done a little research about rule engine in jena, config rule and data in server side using assmbler, it seems inference load data into memory in runtime. Am I correct?

Comment: It would be a feature of the server if it offered the dataset with inference. It is possible to have inference in the server.